# react-bootstrap: remove 'active' after button was clicked

Tags: react-bootstrap

If i click the 'Default' button on [react-bootstrap page](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html) it remains "clicked".
What is the common way to remove the active state, so that the button looks like before it was clicked?

Overriding with the following css does not work:

```
.btn-default:active {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    outline-offset: none !important;
}
```

Use this, In my case, it was solved.

Comment: Please don't ever remove the outline without providing an alternative way of visually showing when the element has focus. Visually impaired people will thank you. To learn why removing outlines is bad practice read: https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not "active", but "focus" and it is fixed by the following css overrides:

```
.btn-default:active, .btn-default:focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever remove the outline without providing an alternative way of visually showing when the element has focus. Visually impaired people will thank you. To learn why removing outlines is bad practice read: https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

Answer (score 0):

For me, this solution worked:

```css
.btn-default:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

You don't even need !important.

Answer (score 0):

add class to your button and

```
.youtclass{
              box-shadow: none;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used .blur (which required a TypeScript type guard):

```
const onChange = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  ...
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
    e.target.blur();
  }
```